# how to implement If-Modified-Since HTTP Header in datalife engine

Tags: php, datalife-engine

By default, pages generated with PHP are not cached by browsers or proxies, as they are generated anew every time the page is loaded by the server. If you have repeat visitors to your website, or even many visitors that use the same proxy, this means that a lot of bandwidth is wasted transferring content that hasn't changed since last time. By adding appropriate code to your PHP pages, you can allow your pages to be cached, and reduce the required bandwidth. Now, how can I do this in datalife engine?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use CDN services like cloudflare.com or any CDN, it will help you a lot more than modify the php code especially if your site that getting heavy with ton of posts in DLE will save you bunch!